# how to simplify a equality statement

Tags: coq

In hypothesis, I have a natural number that cannot be zero.When we add this number 
to an another function,whose output is also natural number. I have to prove that result of addition of these two values equal to zero is false. I should not dig about f,because addition of anything in non zero term ,become equal to zero is false statement.

`H : (m =? 0) = false

(f+ m =? 0) = false`

Comment: Can you edit your title to "how to simplify a boolean equality statement on nat" it will be helpful to other users of stackoverflow.

Comment: You can `destruct m as [ | m'].`  Then you get two cases, and in the first one you get the contradiction `H':true=false.` and can dismiss that.  In the second case you now have `m = S m'` which is different from `0` as you requested.

Comment: `Goal forall m n, m =? 0 = false -> n+m =? 0 = false. now destruct m, n; inversion 1. Qed.`

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer:

```
Require Import Lia.

rewrite !Nat.eqb_neq; lia.
```

## Long answer:

I feel sorry that this question arises.  Historically, most of the reasoning in Coq about equality is done with the `eq` concept, with the notation `m = n`, not with the boolean equality, on which you rely here.  It is also important to know that Coq has a specific notation for "disequality" or "non-equality" : `m <> n` stands for `~ (m = n)`.

So if you add typed the following statement instead, there would be an easy solution:

```
Require Import Arith Lia.

Lemma example1 f m : m <> 0 -> f + m <> 0.
Proof. lia. Qed.
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for the way you express your statement:

```
Lemma example2 f m : (m =? 0) = false -> (f + m =? 0) = false.
Proof. 
Fail lia.
```

If you call `Search` with the following pattern, you see that the boolean comparison expression is logically equivalent to basic equality, but only if you use specific theorems to express this:

```
Search (_ =? _).

Nat.eqb_refl: forall x : nat, (x =? x) = true
beq_nat_refl: forall n : nat, true = (n =? n)
Nat.eqb_sym: forall x y : nat, (x =? y) = (y =? x)
Nat.eqb_spec: forall x y : nat, Bool.reflect (x = y) (x =? y)
beq_nat_eq: forall n m : nat, true = (n =? m) -> n = m
beq_nat_true: forall n m : nat, (n =? m) = true -> n = m
Nat.eqb_eq: forall n m : nat, (n =? m) = true <-> n = m
beq_nat_false: forall n m : nat, (n =? m) = false -> n <> m
Nat.eqb_neq: forall x y : nat, (x =? y) = false <-> x <> y
Nat.pow2_bits_eqb: forall n m : nat, Nat.testbit (2 ^ n) m = (n =? m)
Nat.bit0_eqb: forall a : nat, Nat.testbit a 0 = (a mod 2 =? 1)
Nat.eqb_compare:
  forall x y : nat, (x =? y) = match x ?= y with
                           | Eq => true
                           | _ => false
                           end
Nat.setbit_eqb:
  forall a n m : nat,
  Nat.testbit (Nat.setbit a n) m = ((n =? m) || Nat.testbit a m)%bool
Nat.clearbit_eqb:
  forall a n m : nat,
  Nat.testbit (Nat.clearbit a n) m = (Nat.testbit a m && negb (n =? m))%bool
Nat.testbit_eqb: forall a n : nat, Nat.testbit a n = ((a / 2 ^ n) mod 2 =? 1)
```

But there is no theorem that expresses the interaction of addition with equality to 0.  You can also see this using a more precise pattern.

```
Search (_ =? _) 0 (_ + _).
```

This returns nothing.

On the other hand, if you type

```
Search (_ = _) 0 (_ + _).
```

You see many theorems, one of which is relevant to your problem.

```
Nat.eq_add_0: forall n m : nat, n + m = 0 <-> n = 0 /\ m = 0
```

And this one is enough to solve the problem, if it is expressed with `_ = _` instead of `_ =? _`.  So to solve your specific problem, we need first to transform comparisons using `_ =? _` into equality statements,and then do logical reasoning using the available theorems.  In the first search result, we have the theorem `Nat.eqb_neq` that is adapted to your situation.   Continuing on the proof of `example2` above, we can write:

```
Rewrite !Nat.eqb_neq.

The goal becomes:

f, m : nat
============================
m <> 0 -> f + m <> 0
```

Now, we could do logical reasoning using the theorem `Nat.eq_add_0`.

```
rewrite Nat.eq_add_0.
```

We can finish the proof by small step like this.

```
intros mn0 [fis0 mis0]; case mn0; assumption.
```

we can also ask an automatic tool to finish the proof for us:

```
tauto.
```

But going a little backward in time, we can also observe the statement after rewriting with Nat.eqb_neq.  This is a statement in linear arithmetic (it contains comparisons, natural numbers, and no product between variables).  This statement is in the scope of a tactic for this theory, the one used most often now is `lia`.